# Can a Champion use a polearm and shield?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, shield

I'm building a Champion of Shelyn and like the glaive, but I planned on being the group tank. Is there a way in 2E for someone to use something heavier than a buckler while wielding a polearm?

Comment: Do you mean heavier in terms of Bulk? Or are you asking about the handedness of the Polearm?

Comment: Thank you for asking, I didn't realize that wasn't clear. Edited to fix.

Comment: @AriaNicholas are you committed to a specific ancestry and/or heritage?

Comment: Not particularly, but I'm planning on using it for Pathfinder Society, so pretty much all the options have to be uncommon. She was originally going to be a human.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## You cannot use actual physical shields while using a polearm

But you have other options to increase your AC and reduce the damage taken.

**I would either go all-in with the Inspire Defense route, or very light, with one of the ancestries.**

### The simplest option is an arcane spellcaster multiclass<sup>1</sup>

As Champions have a reason to pump Charisma, I would go with a Sorcerer.

**Sorcerer Dedication**

The dedication gives you 2 cantrips, take [Shield](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=280) *and* [Glass Shield](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1333). Your Champion's Reaction is probably better than either, so you should not use the cantrip's reaction unless the enemy attacks only you. If you trigger the one and become unable to cast it for 10 minutes, you can just switch to the other. I would start with Glass Shield.<sup>1</sup>
2nd level Champion feats are not great, most people take another 1st level feat, so spending on a Dedication is not a high price. Even better with Free Archetype however.

**Basic Sorcerer Spellcasting**

With [Basic Sorcerer Spellcasting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=735) you can pick up [Shielded Arm](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1378). It provides double the AC bonus of the cantrips, but it takes 3 actions to get it going, which is horrible (2 actions to cast, 1 to Raise Shield). It might be ok if you Strike and Cast in the 1st turn then Strike twice and Raise Shield in the 2nd. If you need to Stride on your first turn, just cast one of the cantrips.
[Dancing Shield](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1111) is better, in that its casting includes a Raise a Shield, but you lack the flexibility of Shielded Arm. With the latter if you decide not to Raise the Shield in a specific turn nothing happens, but Dancing Shield ends in this case. Once you have both of these spells, I would retrain the Dedication to get Electric Arc instead of Glass Shield.
For the 3rd level spell I would pick up [Haste](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=147), you will need all the actions you can get, as described above.

### Inspire Defense

Not really a shield, but benefits the whole party. It takes 3 class feats:

- [Bard Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=677) (2 cantrips, one could be Shield), pick Maestro Muse
- [Basic Muse's Whispers](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=679) gives you a 1st or 2nd level Bard feat:

  - Lingering Composition is great if you have a good Charisma and can afford pumping Performance
  - Reach Spell can be used with Lay on Hands
  - Cantrip Expansion gives you 2 extra cantrips (I would use
  - Bardic Lore through Multifarious Muse might be useful your best option if you do not plan on increasing Charisma after the necessary 14
- [Advanced Muse's Whispers](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=680) finally gives you [Inspire Defense](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=188)

While this is the costliest option, it gives +1 **status** bonus to AC *and* saving throws for the whole party, and some small physical resistance. It is even compatible with the Shield spell.

### Ancestry feats

**Shield as Innate Spell**

Many Heritages and Ancestry feats can give you a cantrip (like Otherworldy Magic, Ancient Elf, Wellspring Gnome, Arcane Tattoos).
Check [Gisher's Guide To Acquiring Common Cantrips](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XVv9VXY06APzORcPiu_V2l854C6G_z3xTFnoE3MU5Es/edit).

**Shield-like actions**

If you plan on never blocking, taking Azarketi or Conrasu as your ancestry can free up the above class feats. These are not really shields, but provide a +1 circumstance bonus to AC for 1 action:

- [Hydraulic Deflection](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2299) (Azarketi 1) has the concentrate trait, so mostly does not provoke Attacks of Opportunity, but is hindered by [stupefied](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=37)
- [Ceremony of Protection](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2776) (Conrasu 1) has the manipulate trait, so hard to use while grabbed, and impossible while restrained

Conrasu is rare, but the racial ability boosts and flaws are great for a low Charisma Champion.
Azarketi are uncommon, and quite slow, unless you take the [Mistbreath](https://2e.aonprd.com/Heritages.aspx?ID=195) heritage.

---

1. Primal casters have no access to Shield, Occult and Divine cannot cast Glass Shield
2. At the beginning of an encounter dealing damage to the enemy is more beneficial, towards the end preventing damage to you

Comment: it might be worth adding some example Ancestry feats that allow for someone to grab a cantrip (e.g. shield) like Otherworldy Magic, Ancient Elf, Wellspring Gnome, Arcane Tattoos... etc

Answer (score 6):

### Spells

There are a few spells that grant the benefits of a shield without requiring a free hand, which could be acquired through spellcasting [archetypes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx) or various alternatives like 1st-level [ancestry feats](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=17) or items like the 3rd-level [*dusty rose prism aeon stone*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=407):

- *[shield](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=280)*: cantrip, grants +1 circumstance AC, Hardness 5–25, one Shield Block each 10 minutes

  - If gained through a [Psychic Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3736) choosing [The Tangible Dream](https://2e.aonprd.com/ConsciousMinds.aspx?ID=5) as a conscious mind, it can be amped up to Hardness 50 or allow up to 3 Shield Blocks, and can protect an ally instead
- [*glass shield*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1333): cantrip, grants +1 circumstance AC, Hardness 2-12, reflect damage if Broken, after Broken can't Shield Block for 10 minutes
- *[shielded arm](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1378)*: 1st-rank spell, can Raise a Shield with own arm for 1 minute, Hardness 4–20, can Shield Block but spell ends if too much damage
- [*dancing shield*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1111): 2nd-rank spell, Raise a Shield/Shield Block for an ally by Sustaining up to 1 minute, uses an actual physical shield

> Some effects target or require an ally, or otherwise refer to an ally. This must be someone on your side, often another PC, but it might be a bystander you are trying to protect. You are not your own ally.

Unfortunately *dancing shield* specifies that you're protecting an [ally](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=353), so this wouldn't work to protect your champion if they cast it.

### Ancestry Options

Beyond picking up one of the Cantrips or other spells via ancestry feats, there are also a few actions that specific ancestries have to gain a circumstance bonus to AC like a shield, if you're playing a [conrasu](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2776) or [azarketi](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2299).

If azarketi are common in your campaign setting (such as in Absalom or around the Inner Sea), then you could pick up their Hydraulic Deflection feat after taking [Adopted Ancestry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=751). Conrasu are rare as adventurers even within the Mwangi Expanse where they're typically located, but if the campaign setting  has them common regardless then you'd still need an exoskeleton to expand for their ability.

### Equipment

As you've noted, pretty much just the [buckler](https://2e.aonprd.com/Shields.aspx?ID=1) is an option when wielding a two-handed weapon, though you'd need to drop a hand (free action) off of the polearm to Raise a Shield and fix your grip (one action) before Striking with the polearm.

Further support for the buckler does exist if you're capable/interested in taking a [Swashbuckler Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1859) to pick up the [Buckler Expertise](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1512) feat, increasing the +1 circumstance to AC to +2. Otherwise at higher levels there's also a specific magic buckler in the [*floating shield*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=319) that would allow you to gain the Raise a Shield bonus while having both hands occupied.

There is a [harnessed shield](https://2e.aonprd.com/Shields.aspx?ID=9) which would help if the glaive was a jousting weapon, but maybe your GM might allow for something similar that functions for the glaive.

### For Your Champion

If their ancestry has some 1st-level Feat allowing them to cast *shield* or *glass shield* or some alternative then that would likely be best. It certainly wouldn't be as defensive as an actual steel shield but in exchange you can wield the powerful 2-handed glaive.

Otherwise taking a Psychic Dedication at level 2 to gain a much stronger *shield* would be ideal, requiring either 14 Int or 14 Charisma but letting you block much more frequently and giving versatility with the option to protect an ally instead. One huge benefit is that the champion would gain an additional Focus Point, allowing further castings of *lay on hands* or this amped 3-layer *shield* as needed.

Worth noting as an exception is the [Ancient Elf](https://2e.aonprd.com/Heritages.aspx?ID=34) heritage, allowing even a 1st-level character to pick up the dedication.

Comment: Dancing Shield can target you, not only an ally. The best option is probably [Shielded Arm](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1378)

Comment: Any shield will work if you are dropping your hand off your halberd in order to raise it. The only benefit to having a buckler is that you can hold something (but not wield a weapon) *while* it is raised. You can still use a hand occupied by a wooden/steel shield as long as you're not also trying to use the shield.

Comment: @Ifusaso Non-buckler [shields](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=212) need to "be wielded in one hand to make use of it". Drawing out a shield and raising it would be even worse action economy.

Comment: @brandon, as we discussed many times, the first sentence is most likely fluff.

Comment: There's way to do this at level one through e.g. [Otherworldy Magic](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=17), [Ancient Elf](https://2e.aonprd.com/Heritages.aspx?ID=34), [Wellspring Gnome](https://2e.aonprd.com/Heritages.aspx?ID=15), [Arcane Tattoos](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=938), etc.

Answer (score 4):

### You cannot wield a glaive and actual shield

There is currently no option that allows you to overcome a weapon requiring two hands to wield, nor shields requiring a whole hand to wield.* It's hard to prove a negative, but I'm not familiar with any such ability and a [search of Feats with "Shield"](https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?q=shield&include-types=feat&display=list) in them did not reveal any results. Nimble Shield Hand seemed promising but specifically disallows weapon wielding.

*Note: [Bucklers](https://2e.aonprd.com/Shields.aspx?ID=1) allow you to do some things with your hand, but less than Pathfinder 1e. They only allow you to use that hand to hold items and similar things with it Raised.

> You can Raise a Shield with your buckler as long as you have that hand free or are holding a light object that’s not a weapon in that hand.

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to get at. Bucklers note specifically what they allow... you can use it as long as your hand isn't too busy. I would say being able to use one or the other with an Action tax *barely* counts as wielding both, if at all.

Comment: Thanks, was comparing to Pathfinder 1e, which had more flexible buckler options. Who needs context? haha